# Expanding drop down menu on hover using css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, navbar

I'm trying to get a drop down menu for my navbar so that when I hover over the tabs it opens a drop down menu with more options. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sqx2efw/) of my code. The very final product should look like [this](https://s24.postimg.org/cnrdy5pg5/hover.png), for now I just want to fix the drop down on hover part of it.

Here is a snippet of code im using in css to try and achieve this:

```
.dropdown {
    display: none
}

.navbar-list li:hover .dropdown {
    display: relative;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You are trying wrong approach, check my answer

Comment: @LokeshGupta I tried `display:block;` already, it's not working.

Comment: check update answer by fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is wrong, and you need to use `display: block` on hover, not `display: relative`

But re: the HTML, a `ul` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. You need to nest the dropdowns in an `li`. That is not only correct markup, but it allows the hover to persist when you hover over an `li` that has nested menus. Otherwise, you would need to use `li:hover + .dropdown` to show the next `.dropdown` menu, but your `:hover` will stop once your mouse moves off of the `li`.

Also, each `ul.dropdown` that is in a single nested nav element could probably just be `li`'s of a single `ul`, but what you have isn't incorrect, so I didn't change that.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none
}

.navbar-tags:hover > .dropdown {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-list a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-tags {
  margin: 20px;
}

.navbar-tags, .dropdown { 
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-list">
  <li class="navbar-tags">
    <a href="#">OUR DNA</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Risk</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Adventure Sport</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Entertainment</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Collegiate</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Individual</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Commercial</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">RESEARCH</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Corporate Survey</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Individual Survey</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">STORIES</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would whoever downvoted me please explain why? I'd like to know if I made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I just have one last question, how can I align the options that drop down to the left of the tabs?

Comment: @shortcut you're welcome. remove the default padding. updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying wrong approach, please change your css part

```
.navbar-list li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}


<ul class="navbar-list">
    <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">OUR DNA</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="">Risk</a></li>
</ul>
   </li>
```

**[update code](https://jsfiddle.net/2sqx2efw/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Your HTML structure is wrong.

2) use `display: block` instead of `display: relative`.

**Change your Code Like THis :**

```css
.dropdown {
    display: none
}

.navbar-list li:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-list a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-tags {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-list">
            <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">OUR DNA</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Risk</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Professional</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Adventure Sport</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Entertainment</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Collegiate</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Individual</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Commercial</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">RESEARCH</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Corporate Survey</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Individual Survey</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-tags"><a href="#">STORIES</a></li>
        </ul>
```